# What is the proper way to delete a zombie API proxy in my OPDK installation?

Tags: apigee

I am on an OPDK installation of Apigee Edge.  I have a zombie API proxy, meaning I can't delete the API proxy in the UI (and usually not via MS API, either).  I get the following error:

[image]

What is the best way to ensure Apigee Edge is cleared of this zombie API proxy so that I can redeploy this API proxy again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clean up this up, you will need to execute some manual steps:

1) check /o/{}/apiproxies from MS API call ("curl http(s)://{mgmt-host}:{port}/v1/o/{orgname}/e/{envname}/apiproxies") This will give you the actual response info that the UI is -trying- to parse

2) delete the /o/{}/apiproxies/{proxyname} using MS API call ("curl -X DELETE http(s)://:/v1/o/{orgname}/e/{envname}/apiproxies/{apiproxy_name}") Re-check step 1 to see if it is cleaned up

3) if it is clean, try your deployment again. If it succeeds, you are good.

4) if it does not, then

5) go to zookeeper (/opt/apigee//share/zookeeper) and run the CLI (./zkCli.sh)

6) find /organizations/{orgname}/environments/{envname}/apiproxies/ and see if the {apiproxy_name} is there.

7) if so, execute "[{prompt-stuff}] rmr /organization/{orgname}/environment/{envname}/apiproxies/{apiproxy_name}" in zk

8) repeat your checks above, the proxy should be all clean

Note: There a few circumstances that may require some addition steps, such as actually incorrect server configurations, or conflicting confg data.

Hope that helps.